# Создание приложения переносимого между различными дистрибутивами линукса

Tags: linux, docker, app, portability

К примеру у меня есть некоторое приложение, написанное на с++ и используещее некоторое количество специфических библиотек. В приложении также отсутствует графика. Идеальным вариантом для создания полностью переносимого приложения было бы использование докер контейнера на основе дистрибутива debian, содержащего само приложение и все необходимые зависимости к нему, если бы не одно НО... Приложение, запущенное юзером, должно иметь прямой доступ к `root` директории компьютера на котором оно запущено. Конечно можно было бы примонтировать корневую директорию компа к какой-нибудь директории внутри контейнера, однако в таком случае пути к файлам на хосте не будут совпадать с путями в контейнере к этим же файлам, что ломает всю логику приложения. Думал также над использованием appimage, но эта штука не обеспечивает достаточный уровень переносимости даже между debian:buster и debian:bullseye (при попытке создать appimage со всеми зависимостями получаю ошибку от `linux-vdso`).

Вообщем вопрос: какие есть еще варианты создания переносимого приложения на линуксе?

Comment: тащите с собой необходимые библиотеки. например, в [drweb](http://repo.drweb.com) именно так и сделано.

Comment: по поводу вопроса «какие есть еще варианты создания переносимого приложения на линуксе?» — такие вопросы тут подлежат закрытию: на них невозможно дать объективный ответ.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin если не учитывать предисторию, то да, но выше описана вполне конкретная ситуация (может быть не достаточно подробно или понятно, но тем не менее), так что просьба не рассматривать одно предложение из текста как сферического коня в вакууме.

Comment: если б этой фразы не было, был бы замечательный вопрос. а с нею вопрос сразу превращается в того самого сферического коня, который подлежит закрытию.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin может знаете как это предложение изменить, чтобы оно лучше отражало всю суть вопроса?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin что касается примера, то не имею возможности посмотреть как оно реализавано, но подозреваю, что никакого отношения к текущей проблеме это не имеет. Обычно такие тулы просто имеют набор предкомпилированных пакетов для различных популярных систем (например будут различные пакеты для ubuntu16, ubuntu18 и ubuntu20), а сдесь ни о какой переносимости уже речи не идет от слова совсем

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin хотя все же имею возможность посмотреть и да, дела обстоят ровно так, как я описал выше

Comment: суть вашего вопроса: как сделать переносимый блоб. это уже само по себе очень широко и вряд ли как-то конкретизируемо. а последнее предложение — лишь вишенка на торте. // `подозреваю, что никакого отношения к текущей проблеме это не имеет` — ну, я б не привёл ссылку на сайт своего текущего работодателя, если б не был на 100% уверен, что там реализовано именно то, что вам требуется. нет, там нет набора блобов для разных дистрибутивов. собственно, для одной архитектуры там одни и те же блобы (и необходимая для их запуска скриптовая обвязка).

Comment: http://repo.drweb.com/drweb/debian/dists/ — это не версии для разных дистрибутивов, как вы, вероятно, подумали, это версии самих наборов программ. 11.1 — текущая версия. для всех deb-основных дистрибутивов архитектуры amd64 будут устанавливаться вот эти пакеты: http://repo.drweb.com/drweb/debian/dists/11.1/non-free/binary-amd64/. и от rpm-пакетов, лежащих там же, содержимое фактически не отличается. посмотрите, как там реализован запуск, ну, например, /opt/drweb-com/bin/drweb-configd (это shell-скрипт, который в результате должен запустить блоб drweb-configd.real).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin не совсем... Я про то что мне нужна переносимость блоба. В вашем примере блоб может и переносим, тем не менее сам пакет - нет. К примеру взять пример с докер контейнером - вам не нужно знать еа какой системе он будет запущен, достаточно лишь поддержка докера. Собственно он и был бы идеален, если бы не пути, но решить эту проблему легче, чем писать десяток обвязок к разным дистрибутивам.

Comment: не надо писать обвязок к разным дистрибутивам. посмотрите, всё-таки, как сделано в том, ссылки на что я привёл. deb- и rpm-пакеты — это всего лишь средство доставки блобов, не более того. а блобы внутри ровно одни и те же.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ок, спасибо

Comment: ну, кстати, вроде бы, когда-то у drweb существовало и публичное средство доставки в виде не deb/rpm-пакетов, а в виде банальных tar-болов. сейчас оно не публикуется и используется лишь для внутренних нужд (в процессе сборки пакетов и run-ов). суть там ровно та же самая — те же самые файлы, но без deb/rpm-обвязки.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, _средство доставки блобов_ это где-то восьмая, а то и десятая часть того, для чего необходимы пакетные менеджеры. Почитайте RTFM что ли?

Comment: Автору: вы до сих пор не слышали про системный вызов `chroot()`? Да и вообще с этим докерами-шмокерами люди разучились писать программы UNIX way.

Comment: @0andriy нет... Блин, мне нужно таки собраться и вконце концов открыть книгу по линукс апи. Мне кажется это ровно то, что нужно, правда пока нет времени проверить

Comment: 'chroot` это вариант. Но есть и еще. Я так понимаю, что пользователь не будет запускать приложение выполняя команду `docker run ...`. Значит будет скрипт, который красиво все скроет от пользователя. А значит скрипт знает куда в файловой системе контейнера подключается `/root` с хоста и  может передать приложению параметр, где искать директорию для работы (т.е. не прошивать в приложении жестко `/root`, а чтоб это было параметром приложения) внутри контейнера.

Comment: @RomanKonoval вы вопрос хоть прочитали?